# Sed/grep results into formatted excel file

Tags: excel, sed, grep

I'm looking for a way to output the results of my sed/grep query into an excel file where it detects the use of columns.

So, I'm using the following

```
sed '/b[A-Za-z0-9._%]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}/b' pool.txt | egrep "example" > names.xls
```

Which gives the following

```
test.123@example.com    FirstName LastName
```

What would be the best method for throwing this into an excel file with 2 columns for email | name?

Comment: Provide sample input and output ?

Comment: I'd have to redact a lot of information to give input samples.  It's basically a bunch of system information, username, email address, fullname so, my sed statement is working fine and it's grepping what I need.  I've given the output (email address & name) and I'm looking to format that into 2 columns for use in Excel

Comment: I can't test an answer without sample input.